# fail safe iterators and weakly consistent iterators

Tags: java, collections

Fail safe iterators are those which do not `throw` `ConcurrentModificationException`.

But what is the difference between `fail safe iterators` and `weakly consistent iterators`?

Are both same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14084104/469220

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084104/concurrenthashmap-returns-a-weakly-consistent-iterator-why-should-we-use-it-any

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both `Fail-safe` and `Weakly consistent` iterators do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

**`weakly consistent iterators:`** Collections which rely on CAS(*compare-and-swap*) have weakly consistent iterators, which reflect some but not necessarily all of the changes that have been made to their backing collection since they were created. For example, if elements in the collection have been modified or removed before the iterator reaches them, it definitely will reflect these changes, but no such guarantee is made for insertions.

**`Fail safe iterator`** iterator mechanism makes a copy of the internal Collection data structure and uses it to iterate over the elements. This prevents any concurrent modification exceptions from being thrown if the underlying data structure changes. Of course, the overhead of copying the entire array is introduced.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` is one such implementation with Fail safe iterator, which we can easily see by looking at the constructor's source:

```
public CopyOnWriteArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        Object[] elements = c.toArray();

        if (elements.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length, Object[].class);
        setArray(elements);
    }
```

**Reference:**

1. `Java Generics and Collections: 11.5. Collections and Thread Safety`
2. [`Iterators – Fail fast Vs Fail safe`](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2009/09/iterators-fail-fast-vs-fail-safe/)